# How to quickly test sending HTML+embedded images for email?

Tags: email, html

I need to test how well some HTML code works when sent over email (as opposed to being opened in a browser via http). The page will contain images and they will need to be embedded in the email. Sounds easy, we send HTML mails every day, don't we?

Well, the usual email software I see around will present you a [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) editor, they'll spit their html interpretation of what you write in the editor and will let you put images in the "document" that will be automatically embedded... they don't let you put your own HTML code without modifications.

I also took a quick look at PHPlist, but it seems overkill and too complicated to put up for a single developer for testing purposes and it seem easy to send HTML code but a little more difficult to embed images.

What software or technique can I use to quickly send an HTML email with embedded images?

I'm looking for a quick solution for testing purposes, doesn't need to be able to send thousands of mails. It could be something over the web (LAMP preferred but perl/python/ruby available) or on the desktop (MacOSX preferred but linux/windows available).

Please note I must let "creative" people send emails, they are not programmers and can't make use of source code.

Answer (score 0):

here is a working solution for windows using .NET :

http://www.mail-archive.com/ntsysadmin@lyris.sunbelt-software.com/msg92403.html

Comment: Doesn't that need Visual Studio or something like that installed on the system? I'm looking for something useable, not for source code to write apps...

Comment: you can save the code provided in a file named *.ps1 the run this file in powershell. You mentionned you've looked at PHP so I guess you re not affraid to adapt this script ... :)

Comment: Didn't know about the powershell thingie, thanks for pointing that out. Adapting a script won't be a problem, getting Visual Studio on the system would have been.